# What does scheme with an action mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

What is the meaning of the following quote?

"A graded Artin A-algebra over a field is the same as an artinian scheme with an action of the multiplicative group. "

My main problem is understanding what a scheme with an action is.

Comment: Have you hear about group actions in general?

Comment: Yes, I have heard of group actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most categories where automorphisms make sense, group action will make sense. For example, in the category of schemes, for any $S$, $\mathrm{Aut}(S)$, the set of all isomorphisms from $S$ to itself is a group and a group action by a group $G$ is just a group homomorphism $G\to\mathrm{Aut}(S)$.

In particular, if $A$ is an Artin ring over a field and if $\mathbb{G}_m$, the multiplicative group acts on it (for convenience, let me assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, though not necessary), then $A$ can be written as a graded ring, $\oplus_{n\geq 0} V_n$ where $V_n$ is the set of elements of $A$ where the group acts by $n^{th}$ power. That is, $v\in V_n$ if and only if $a\cdot v=a^nv$, where $\cdot$ stands for the action and the right hand side is just multiplication, for any $a\in \mathbb{G}_m$. Conversely, if $A=\oplus_{n\geq 0}V_n$ is a graded ring, there is a natural action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ given by $a\cdot v=a^nv$ for all $a\in\mathbb{G}_m$ and all $v\in V_n$.

Just as a note, even more generally, we can define all these as maps, never saying anything about actual points. For example a $\mathbb{G}_m$ action on a scheme $S$ is just a morphism $\mathbb{G}_m\times S\to S$, satisfying some obvious properties.